# Do I need to free GtkListStore when setting a new model?

Tags: c, model, gtk, free, gtk3

I am writing a program in `C` and using `Gtk+` for the GUI. Everything works fine, but I have some doubts about possible **memory leaks**.

I need to show a list of elements and then filter this list by means of a search bar and buttons. I thought to use a `GtkTreeView` with a `GtkListStore` as described in this [example](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/TreeWidget.html).

When a filtering is performed I simply create a new `GtkListStore` and populate it with new elements and then set the new model in the `GtkTreeView`.

**Do I need to free those models I am not using anymore or will `Gtk+` automatically handle it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asserting you use `gtk_tree_view_set_model` to swap models.

docbook
gtk_tree_view_set_model ()

```
void                gtk_tree_view_set_model             (GtkTreeView *tree_view,
                                                         GtkTreeModel *model);
```

> Sets the model for a GtkTreeView. If the tree_view already has a model
>   set, it will remove it before setting the new model. If model is NULL,
>   then it will unset the old model.

So this means that if a model is associated with the view its referece counter will decrease by one (I actually verfied that by a look into the source, the documentation is not explicit enough here what "remove" means)).

If you handle it as the example says

```
   /* Create a view */
   tree = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model (GTK_TREE_MODEL (store));

   /* The view now holds a reference.  We can get rid of our own
    * reference */
   g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (store));
```

you do not need to do anything additionally *unless* you explicitly call `g_object_ref` or some other method which will add reference.

I strongly suggest you to get [devhelp](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Devhelp) and install the `Gtk+` docbook entries.